# Create multiple dataframes or vectors by automation with vector names

Tags: r, function, dataframe, vectorization

Simply put in this example, I have a vector with 3 directions:

**vector <- c("South", "North", "East")**

And I need to create a new vector for each of the directions and name the 3 new vectors after each direction. So I expected the logic below to work:

**for(i in 1:length(vector){
  data.*vector[i]* <- c(1:3)**

And it would create 3 vectors (data.South, data.North and data.East) all 3 equal to (1,2,3).

Unfortunately, this does not work as the vector reference *vector[1]* is read by R as a nonexistent dataframe:

**Error in data.vector[1] <- "Position" : object 'data.vector' not found**

Is there a way I can code it and get the 3 new vectors created?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach that is very similar to the way you are asking is with `assign`:

```
for(i in seq_along(vector)){
assign(vector[[i]],data.frame())
}
ls()
[1] "East"             "North"             "South"
```

Another approach is to create a list object where each element is a `data.frame`, like this:

```
lapply(vector, function(x){setNames(data.frame(x),x)})
[[1]]
  South
1 South

[[2]]
  North
1 North

[[3]]
  East
1 East
```

Comment: Actually,  `lapply(vector, function(x){setNames(data.frame(x),x)})` creates df as element of a list, but they are not empty. To get a list with 3 empty df with names "data.X" it can be `sapply(paste("data", vector, sep="."), assign, data.frame())`.

Comment: Also to get df's from a vector of names `data <- sapply(vector, assign, data.frame())` so that they an be accessed as `data$South` which is similar to the required name `data.South'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create empty dataframes with names in `vector`, one way would be :

```
list_data <- setNames(replicate(length(vector), data.frame()), 
                      paste0('data.', vector))
list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

However, consider using lists (`list_data`) as they are easier to manage and do not pollute the global environment.